# Redis pub/sub limit

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

Using Redis pub/sub, is there a way to limit the number of listeners that Redis will publish to?

http://redis.io/commands/publish

For example, using Node.js parlance:

```
var redis = require('redis');
var rcPub = redis.createClient();
var rcSub = redis.createClient();

rcPub.publish('channel','messageA',{limit:1}); //desired functionality/syntax
```

basically, when I send messageA to Redis, I want to tell Redis to publish the message to only one listener/subscriber. Seems possible, but can Redis do this?

In the Redis docs, the command is:

```
PUBLISH channel message
```

what I am looking for is:

```
PUBLISH channel message limit
```

where limit is an integer. Seems reasonable, and easy to implement from Redis' perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a channel per subscribed, and then publish to a single user's channel when you need to communicate with him.